# Custom Crypto Provider

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Как можно добавить свой криптопровайдер для все системы? Например я добавил свой криптопровайдер в приложении А

```
Provider tmpProv = new tmpProvider();
Security.addProvider(tmpProv);
```

Что мне надо сделать чтобы я увидел ЭТОТ же криптопровайдер в приложении Б?

```
Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
for(Provider provider : providers) {
   Log.d("logba", "onClick : provider="+provider.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Явно никак, т.к. если так легко можно было бы добовлять разные библиотеки, то система не была бы защищённой. Для этого необходимо модифицировать прошивку android. И ещё, если вы  добавили в своё приложение класс и думаете, что можно просто обратиться к этому классу из другого приложения, то вы не понимаете основ.